# How do I add launch condition for Windows 7 and above in setup project (VS 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-deployment, launch-condition

I am creating a Setup project using VS 2010, where I want that setup should run only if it is running on Windows 7 or above operating system.

How can I add a launch condition for this in setup and deployment project?

Comment: What tool are you using to create this setup program?

Comment: I am usin VS 2010 --> Setpup & Deployment Project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using wix you can do this. Please see the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733593/how-to-check-the-system-is-windows-7-or-windows-server-2008-r2-in-wix-installer)

Comment: I want to use Setup project only with VS 2010. But it helps me I have added a new launch condition and assign VersionNT >= 601 value to condition property.

Comment: And if you're looking to target other operating systems (not solely Windows 7) you can use the reference table here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372495(v=vs.85).aspx